Kernel Customisation in Jetson Orin Nano
Im trying to edit Linux_for_Tegra/source/kernel/kernel-jammy-src/.config file by addingCONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=512, but When I build the kernel its getting changed to CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=32.
Why is getting changed?
I'm trying to do kernel customisation in Jetson Orin Nano.
Can anyone suggest why is that happening?
I'm trying to do kernel Customisation in Jetson Orin nano dev kit. But the .Config is reverting back everytime.Is there any method to overcome this.
I don't want to use make menuconfig option.
When I Cross-Compile using the following command:
# export CROSS_COMPILE=~<PATH_TO_LOCATION>/bin/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-  

Followed by
# make -C kernel

Its changing the value of CONFIG_CMA_SIXE_MBYTES from 512 to 32.
Is there any other way to prevent it from happening without using menuconfig option?

"I don't want to use make menuconfig option." - Why? Bypassing the menuconfig command means that dependencies will not be checked and autoselections not configured by the Kconfig system.  So manually editing the .config file is discouraged unless you really, really know what you are doing. If you met that qualification, then you probably would not be asking for help.
